# I want to put the media player with each row of listView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I want to put the media player with each row of listView, can any one of you help me in making it....actually its coming in front of my Screen but I want it with the every row of the ListView to Play and pause with all functionality so can any one of you help me in this??

Comment: "media player with each row of listView?" but at time user can listen one song right ?

Comment: Yeah but at a time only one will be visible.....the one which is currently playing actually.....for rest SetVisibility will be Visibility.GONE.

Comment: can create a single media player and show your buttons in list and hanle the event of htem ?

Comment: i was to use build in media player of android which i get by instantiating MediaPlayer class